# TTL to CMOS Different Supply voltages

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, cmos, input

I am designing a circuit using a CD4011 Nand Gate 5 volt Vcc and a CD4555 using a 15 volt vcc. Will the Nand gate High output have enough voltage to drive the input of the CD4555 to a High Output?  <>  Nand Gate High Output = 5 volts
Due to circuit configuration and board space I need to use this circuit.
But I need more drive voltage for another circuit. I will have to build a new board to make this work and I would like to know before I start.
I have tested it using 8 volts on the CD4555 Vcc on another circuit design and it works.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a voltage translator (maybe discrete transistors or a CD40109). Worst-case **11 volts** is required according to the datasheet with a 15V Vdd.

5V is also not enough to guarantee operation with an 8V supply- it will "usually" work, but that's not good design.

Comment: Thank you for your comments I was not sure if the CMOS was designed to work with TTL 5 volt input regardless of the CMOS supply voltage.

Comment: It's a percentage of the supply voltage. The CD4555 datasheet says 7V for a 10V supply and 3.5V for a 5V supply (worst case). That means you'd need 5.6V for an 8V supply (worst case, again). Typically the transition is at around 50% supply or 4V on an 8V supply, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @user66377 [Datasheet for CD4555B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4555b.pdf). You really should get into the habit of reading these. See p2 VIH Min. 11V for VDD=15V as Spehro says.

Comment: I read the data sheet but it was vague on the input for different voltage inputs. After looking at the datasheet you referred me to it was obvious I had looked at a different Manufactures datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

After Studying my circuit I was able to incorporate one extra component and changed a resistor to a diode. I hooked a signal diode cathode to the output of my IC and tied a resistor to the 15 volt supply. Joined the resistor and anode together and tied it to my output circuit that I needed to drive, giving me plenty of drive voltage. I had to increase my current limiter circuit, as now I had more current supplied to my output as a normal situation.
Thank you all for your replies.    vcc --V^V^V--**Gate**--|>|-- IC output
Bob